# Cannot make Task <HttpResponseMessage> "await"

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpclient, async-await

I am trying to write a method in my web api wrapper. I want to make use of "async/await" feature so that UI doesn't get blocked. Below is the code snippet in the web api wrapper.

```
    public static async Task Get<T>(Dictionary<string, string> paramDictionary, string controller)
    {
        try
        {
            string absoluteUrl = BaseUrl + controller + "?";
            absoluteUrl = paramDictionary.Aggregate(absoluteUrl,
                (current, keyValuePair) => current + (keyValuePair.Key + "=" + keyValuePair.Value + "&"));
            absoluteUrl = absoluteUrl.TrimEnd('&');

            using (HttpClient client = GetClient(absoluteUrl))
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(absoluteUrl);
                return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
```

The problem is I get compiler error at the statement below.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(absoluteUrl);
```

It says `"Type System.Threading.Tasks.Task <System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage> is not awaitable"`. After much searching I am not able to get rid of this error. Any ideas where I am going wrong? Please help.

Comment: side note: `throw exception;` will destroy the callstack. Just use `throw;`

Comment: I tried the code in the using block and the first line compiles, but the compiler didn't find the definition of `ReadAsAsync<T>`. Is that an extension method?

Comment: @jgauffin yeah an in addition to that it's not really necessary to catch an exception just for re-throwing it. just remove the whole try catch part here...

Comment: Also awaiting inside a using block is not a good idea, the code returns straight away after starting the async operation and it disposes of `HttpClient`.

Comment: The method can't have `Task` as its return type, because it returns something. Should probably be `Task<T>`.

Comment: Which version of C# and VS are you using?

Comment: @NedStoyanov, *"Also awaiting inside a using block is not a good idea, the code returns straight away after starting the async operation and it disposes of HttpClient"* - not true. It would be true if the OP didn't do `await` inside `using`.

Comment: Are you targeting .Net 4.0 in VS2013? The version of `Task` in .Net 4.0 does not have the required `GetAwaiter` method so it cannot be used with async/await. You can use the async targeting pack to add the required methods.

Comment: @Nosratio, my bad. Does the `using` statement get captured in the generated state machine?

Comment: @NedStoyanov, yep it does, same as as `try/catch/finally` and other C# control flow statements. Although, you cannot `await` inside `catch/finally` (you can inside `try`).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, it's because your method returns `Task`, not `Task<T>`. So you cannot do `return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>()`. Change the signature to return `Task<T>`:

```
public static async Task<T> Get<T>(...)
```

Comment: I tried your way. But didn't work unfortunately..:-(

Comment: @TejasSutar, now that you've changed the signature to `Task<T>`, what's the error message and what line exactly gives it?

Comment: @TejasSutar, are you indeed targeting Net 4.0?

Comment: It's the same error message I mentioned earlier. One more thing I forgot to mention that compiler cannot find definition for ReadAsAsync method. I am referring following site for code:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-clients/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

Comment: Sorry for late @Noseratio. Actually it's a Silverlight project and version is 5. I am not able to find it's .NET version in VS which is usually found in Properties of project.

Comment: @TejasSutar, then besides returning `Task<T>` you also need to add [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async) NuGet package to your Silverlight project, as suggested by @Lee.

Comment: I have already put async besides Task<T>. Does my async differ from one you mentioned @Noseratio?

Comment: @TejasSutar, that's not enough. To use C# 5.0 `async` with Silverlight's subset of .NET runtime, you need add `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package to your project. Follow and read the [link](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async).

Comment: Yes. I just added Microsoft.Bcl.Async using package manager in VS. Now I need to get rid of compiler error at the statement "return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T>();" Thanks for help @Noseratio.

Comment: @TejasSutar, now to get rid of *that* error, return `Task<T>` from your `Get` method.

Comment: Actually compiler is not able to find ReadAsAsync which is an extension method. I tried to install related NuGet package here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.Formatting. But I got some error in the package console manager. Also the package is deprecated as mentioned in that link. So I've to go for some other mechanism to convert HttpResponseMessage object into required class object.

Comment: @TejasSutar, first try adding the most recent `HttpClient` NuGet package (v2.2.22): http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I did the following to get it compile.

1. Add web api 2.2 for the system.net.http.formatting extension dll

[image]

2. Change the method signature from `Task` to `Task<T>`

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Microsoft.Bcl.Build Nuget package worked for me.